# getting value from arraylist in android

Tags: android

I am working on android project. I have an array that stores the data dynamically based on selected data. I also have another array that contians data by default.
My requirement is i will show with example

array1 data - [1,3,5]
array2 data - [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800]

I need to get the data of second array based on first array data. i.e first array1[0] contains 1,So i need to get array2[1] value
Similarly array1[1] contains 3, so i need to get array2[3] value
Similarly array1[2] contains 5, so i need to get array2[5] value.

How to achieve this task? Please help with this issue.

Comment: `int valueYouWant = array2[array1[0]];` ?

Comment: do i need to write a loop for this?

Comment: If you want all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for, but if you want to have your data in some output list, try this:

```
final List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (final int x : arrayOfInts1) {
       output.add(arrayOfInts2[x]);
}
```

`arrayOfInts1` contains indexes to fetch `from arrayofInts2`. This code will extract contents of `arrayOfInts2` based on positions from `arrayOfInts1`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have to try this way.

```
int [] arr1={0,1,2};
int [] arr2={10,20,30};

      if(arr1.length==arr2.length){
            for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
                int val=arr2[arr1[i]];
            }
     }
```

may be this is helpful.